# Modifying an Entity Framework expression when tables have been remapped

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-core

I have an issue now that a table has had an id removed.

First I had this query below where entity (table) 'RecordsProduct' has a 'DefendnatId' that was mapped to a Defendant table. It was fine!

```
            records = records
                .Include(r => r.Employer)
                .Include(r => r.Contractor)
                .Include(r => r.RecordProducts)
                .ThenInclude(rp => rp.Defendant)
                .Where(r => EF.Functions.Like(r.Employer.DefendantCode, "%" + input.DefendantCode + "%")
                    || EF.Functions.Like(r.Contractor.DefendantCode, "%" + input.DefendantCode + "%")
                    || r.RecordProducts.Any(rp => EF.Functions.Like(rp.Defendant.DefendantCode, "%" + input.DefendantCode + "%") && rp.IsActive == true));
```

That `DefendantId` has been removed from the table and replaced with a `DefendantProductId` from a translation table called `ProductDefendant` like this

`ProductDefendant` table:

- DefendantProductId
- DefendantId
- ProductId

So I can't do this anymore:

```
rp.Defendant.DefendantCode
```

now I have to do this

```
rp.ProductDefendant.Defendant.DefendantCode
```

and now my query is blowing up! Is there anything I can do to modify it to make it faster? Or change the way the joins are working?

```
           records = records
                .Include(r => r.Employer)
                .Include(r => r.Contractor)
                .Include(r => r.RecordProducts)
                .ThenInclude(rp => rp.ProductDefendant.Defendant)
                .Where(r => EF.Functions.Like(r.Employer.DefendantCode, "%" + input.DefendantCode + "%")
                    || EF.Functions.Like(r.Contractor.DefendantCode, "%" + input.DefendantCode + "%")
                    || r.RecordProducts.Any(rp => EF.Functions.Like(rp.ProductDefendant.Defendant.DefendantCode, "%" + input.DefendantCode + "%")
                    && rp.IsActive == true));
```

here is the generated SQL below. I think the problem is in the "Where" clause

```js
SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[StartDate], [t].[EndDate], [t].[WitnessName], [t].[SourceCode], [t].[JobsiteName], [t].[ShipName], [t].[EmployerCode]
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [r].[RecordID] AS [Id], [r].[StartDate], [r].[EndDate], [r.Witness].[FullName] AS [WitnessName], CASE
        WHEN [r].[SourceID] IS NOT NULL
        THEN [r.Source].[SourceCode] ELSE N'zzzzz'
    END AS [SourceCode], CASE
        WHEN [r].[JobsiteID] IS NOT NULL
        THEN [r.Jobsite].[JobsiteName] ELSE N'zzzzz'
    END AS [JobsiteName], CASE
        WHEN [r].[ShipID] IS NOT NULL
        THEN [r.Ship].[ShipName] ELSE N'zzzzz'
    END AS [ShipName], CASE
        WHEN [r].[EmployerID] IS NOT NULL
        THEN [r.Employer].[DefendantCode] ELSE N'zzzzz'
    END AS [EmployerCode]
    FROM [Records] AS [r]
    LEFT JOIN [Ships] AS [r.Ship] ON [r].[ShipID] = [r.Ship].[ShipID]
    LEFT JOIN [Jobsites] AS [r.Jobsite] ON [r].[JobsiteID] = [r.Jobsite].[JobsiteID]
    LEFT JOIN [Sources] AS [r.Source] ON [r].[SourceID] = [r.Source].[SourceID]
    LEFT JOIN [Witnesses] AS [r.Witness] ON [r].[WitnessID] = [r.Witness].[WitnessID]
    LEFT JOIN [Defendants] AS [r.Contractor] ON [r].[ContractorID] = [r.Contractor].[DefendantID]
    LEFT JOIN [Defendants] AS [r.Employer] ON [r].[EmployerID] = [r.Employer].[DefendantID]
    WHERE ([r].[IsActive] = 1) AND (([r.Employer].[DefendantCode] LIKE (N'%' + @__input_DefendantCode_1) + N'%' OR [r.Contractor].[DefendantCode] LIKE (N'%' + @__input_DefendantCode_3) + N'%') OR EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [Records_Products] AS [rp]
        INNER JOIN [Product_Defendant] AS [rp.ProductDefendant] ON [rp].[DefendantProductID] = [rp.ProductDefendant].[DefendantProductID]
        INNER JOIN [Defendants] AS [rp.ProductDefendant.Defendant] ON [rp.ProductDefendant].[DefendantID] = [rp.ProductDefendant.Defendant].[DefendantID]
        WHERE ([rp.ProductDefendant.Defendant].[DefendantCode] LIKE (N'%' + @__input_DefendantCode_5) + N'%' AND ([rp].[IsActive] = 1)) AND ([r].[RecordID] = [rp].[RecordID])))
) AS [t]
ORDER BY [t].[SourceCode]
OFFSET @__p_6 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_7 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: This is just one more join (PK index search) which normally should not affect the query performance significantly. And no, it can't be avoided because the introduced intermediate translation table requires it.

Comment: Yes, I agree it can't be avoided, but it does affect query performance! Very much so...

Comment: This sounds like a database issue more than an EF one. Check what indexes exist to be used by this query.

Comment: The only index I think I need here is on the DefendantId for the join on the Defendant table. And that already exists! But I could be wrong, maybe there is something else needed. I'm not following a code first approach or a database first approach. Just working off former employers work.

Comment: You may also need an index on ProductDefendant.DefendantId (to cover all the foreign keys).

Comment: yes, there is one on ProductDefendant.DefendnatId. I'll post the generated SQl code above, in my post to show what's going on!

Comment: @user1186050 might help to copy the query into sql server management studio, go to query -> include actual execution plan, run the query, click execution plan tab and see if there any suggested indices. often a great place to start tuning effots

Comment: Did that and it shows me that 83% is coming from the sort. So I put an index on the "SourceCode" column but that didn't change anything!

Comment: How about removing the (redundant) `Distinct` operator from the query. The `where` clause looks optimal for this table model. `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY`in combination will all these joins may cause bad execution plan.

Comment: Just an idea. Would it be worth it to create a new project and use the classes to do a code first database migration (to a test database)? That would at least show you what EF would do in the same situation (ie. indices). It might be more work than it is worth though.

Comment: Is the column DefendantCode from type varchar or nvarchar? I had a similar problem with varchar columns. All the string values are nvarchar (N'HereGoesAString'), if your column is varchar the SQL server needs to cast the nvarchar to varchar for each table entry, this could kill your performance. Could you provide a execution plan of the query?

Comment: @user1186050 - Just a suggestion, If you are just trying to get(select) the data from DB and not modifying anything, you can use AsNoTracking() on your DBContect which wont track your changes. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Would you be able to share the "Actual Execution Plan" here? That will give us good idea of what and where is the problem. As you would already know "Seek" is better than "Scan" in execution plan.

Comment: can you show the schema for the table?  Something I've run into is varchar vs nvarchar indexing, if you can't show schema, make sure DefendantCode is nvarchar and not varchar.  Also, I assume since you're using EF and don't mention another DB that you're using MSSQL, can you tag explicitly what DB you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to give you a good advice because the generated SQL query looks fine for that model, and nowadays SQL query optimizers (CBO) should not be affected by the way you write the query like the old RBOs (CBO stands for Cost Based Optimizer, RBO - Rule Based Optimizer). They should be able to turn `EXISTS` or `IN` into `JOIN` (produce the same execution plan as `JOIN`). The only difference between the current SQL and the original is one additional join, which with clustered PK index seek should not affect the performance significantly.

But since you say that, apparently something unknown is causing the CBO to choose a bad plan. And since the plan depends on the data which I don't have, all I can do is to suggest trying two alternative functionally equivalent queries.

First, your current (slow) query seems to be like this:

```
var input = new { DefendantCode = "Abc", Skip = 4, Take = 2 };
var defendantCodePattern = "%" + input.DefendantCode + "%";

var query = db.Set<Record>()
    .Where(r => r.IsActive)
    .Where(r => EF.Functions.Like(r.Employer.DefendantCode, defendantCodePattern)
        || EF.Functions.Like(r.Contractor.DefendantCode, defendantCodePattern)
        || r.RecordProducts.Any(rp => EF.Functions.Like(rp.ProductDefendant.Defendant.DefendantCode, defendantCodePattern))
    )
    .Select(r => new
    {
        ID = r.RecordID,
        StartDate = r.StartDate,
        EndDate = r.EndDate,
        WitnessName = r.Witness.FullName,
        SourceCode = r.Source != null ? r.Source.SourceCode : "zzzzz",
        JobsiteName = r.Jobsite != null ? r.Jobsite.JobsiteName : "zzzzz",
        ShipName = r.Ship != null ? r.Ship.ShipName : "zzzzz",
        EmployeeCode = r.Employer != null ? r.Employer.DefendantCode : "zzzzz",
    })
    //.Distinct()
    .OrderBy(t => t.SourceCode)
    .Skip(input.Skip).Take(input.Take);
```

Some things to mention. First, the query is using projection (`Select`), so the `Include` / `ThenInclude` are not needed (because they are [ignored](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#ignored-includes)). Second, the common search pattern is created and stored outside the query, thus ending up with a sing parameter rather than 3. Third, the `Distinct` is not needed for this query, so I've removed it.

Now the potential attempts to improve the generated SQL query executing speed.

(1) If the `Defendant` related table is not big, you can prefetch the `DefendantID`s matching the search filter, and then use `Contains` (translated to SQL `IN`) for filtering This would help eliminating some of the joins. e.g.

```
var defendantIds = db.Set<Defendant>()
    .Where(d => EF.Functions.Like(d.DefendantCode, defendantCodePattern))
    .Select(d => d.DefendantID)
    .ToList();
```

and then (the second `Where`):

```
.Where(r => defendantIds.Contains(r.Employer.DefendantID)
    || defendantIds.Contains(r.Contractor.DefendantID)
    || r.RecordProducts.Any(rp => defendantIds.Contains(rp.ProductDefendant.Defendant.DefendantID))
)
```

(2) The following trick will replace the `EXISTS` with `LEFT JOIN`. Replace the second `Where` with:

```
.SelectMany(r => r.RecordProducts.DefaultIfEmpty(), (r, rp) => new { r, rp })
.Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.r.Employer.DefendantCode, defendantCodePattern)
    || EF.Functions.Like(x.r.Contractor.DefendantCode, defendantCodePattern)
    || EF.Functions.Like(x.rp.ProductDefendant.Defendant.DefendantCode, defendantCodePattern)
)
.Select(x => x.r)
```

and uncomment the `.Distinct()` (here it is needed because the `LEFT JOIN` (from `SelectMany`) multiplies the source records). The generated SQL in this case looks like this:

```sql
SELECT [t].[ID], [t].[StartDate], [t].[EndDate], [t].[WitnessName], [t].[SourceCode], [t].[JobsiteName], [t].[ShipName], [t].[EmployeeCode]
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [r].[RecordID] AS [ID], [r].[StartDate], [r].[EndDate], [r.Witness].[FullName] AS [WitnessName], CASE
        WHEN [r].[SourceID] IS NOT NULL
        THEN [r.Source].[SourceCode] ELSE N'zzzzz'
    END AS [SourceCode], CASE
        WHEN [r].[JobsiteID] IS NOT NULL
        THEN [r.Jobsite].[JobsiteName] ELSE N'zzzzz'
    END AS [JobsiteName], CASE
        WHEN [r].[ShipID] IS NOT NULL
        THEN [r.Ship].[ShipName] ELSE N'zzzzz'
    END AS [ShipName], CASE
        WHEN [r].[EmployerID] IS NOT NULL
        THEN [r.Employer].[DefendantCode] ELSE N'zzzzz'
    END AS [EmployeeCode]
    FROM [Records] AS [r]
    LEFT JOIN [Ships] AS [r.Ship] ON [r].[ShipID] = [r.Ship].[ShipID]
    LEFT JOIN [Jobsites] AS [r.Jobsite] ON [r].[JobsiteID] = [r.Jobsite].[JobsiteID]
    LEFT JOIN [Sources] AS [r.Source] ON [r].[SourceID] = [r.Source].[SourceID]
    LEFT JOIN [Witnesses] AS [r.Witness] ON [r].[WitnessID] = [r.Witness].[WitnessID]
    LEFT JOIN [Defendants] AS [r.Contractor] ON [r].[ContractorID] = [r.Contractor].[DefendantID]
    LEFT JOIN [Defendants] AS [r.Employer] ON [r].[EmployerID] = [r.Employer].[DefendantID]
    LEFT JOIN [Records_Products] AS [r.RecordProducts] ON [r].[RecordID] = [r.RecordProducts].[RecordID]
    LEFT JOIN [Product_Defendant] AS [r.RecordProducts.ProductDefendant] ON [r.RecordProducts].[DefendantProductID] = [r.RecordProducts.ProductDefendant].[DefendantProductID]
    LEFT JOIN [Defendants] AS [r.RecordProducts.ProductDefendant.Defendant] ON [r.RecordProducts.ProductDefendant].[DefendantID] = [r.RecordProducts.ProductDefendant.Defendant].[DefendantID]
    WHERE ([r].[IsActive] = 1) AND (([r.Employer].[DefendantCode] LIKE @__defendantCodePattern_1 OR [r.Contractor].[DefendantCode] LIKE @__defendantCodePattern_1) OR [r.RecordProducts.ProductDefendant.Defendant].[DefendantCode] LIKE @__defendantCodePattern_1)
  ) AS [t]
ORDER BY [t].[SourceCode]
OFFSET @__p_2 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_3 ROWS ONLY
```

As I said at the very beginning, normally this should not affect the CBO plan. But I definitely see different estimated execution plan from the original, so it's worth trying (although the LINQ query looks ugly).

Comment: The solution I was looking for but couldn't explain, was by changing the query from a exists to a join, I just didn't know how to do it and using a exist was running the query into a 40+ second operation, now it's down to ~10 seconds which is acceptable for my users. thanks for the help